# Oracle - How to read from VARRAY

Tags: sql, oracle, varray

I have a column in my table that contains a VARRAY of VARCHAR2,
So I want to create a select-statement that gives me all the columns
and all the objects of the VARRAY next to eachother,
is there a possible way to do that?

Example:

```
CREATE TYPE arr AS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(10);

CREATE TABLE table1(
    v1 VARCHAR2(10)
    v2 VARCHAR2(20)
    v3 arr);

SELECT t.v1, t.v2, ??? FROM table1 t;
```

Thank You!

Comment: I am just curious, If my solution worked for you.!

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work like I wanted it so I stopped trying!

Answer (score 7):

the one you wanted is this.!

```
SELECT t.v1, t.v2, nt.COLUMN_VALUE
FROM table1 t, TABLE(t.v3) nt
```

**result**

```
V1  V2  COLUMN_VALUE
a   b   c
a   b   d
a   b   e
f   g   h
f   g   i
```

Including t1.v3 also gives the The comma seprated values as well.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a2e7/5)